# R, try or tryCatch without error log

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

I'm smoothing time-series of various lengths. My primary choice is a spline smoothing with the function `smooth.spline()`, to which I provide the argument `nknots`. The nknots argument is based on the length of the series. However it might happen that this function fails to fit a spline, most likely because the number of knots is too small, in which case I'd like to use a rolling average in replacement.

My problem is the following: I tried to embed this operation within a `try()` and within a `tryCatch()` call, but for both cases I can't get rid of the printing of the (numerous!) error messages.

Here is some example code for my `tryCatch()` attempt:

```
Mysmooth.spline <- function(x, winlen, id){
  require(zoo)
  out <- tryCatch(
    {
      # Try to fit a cubic spline
      smooth.spline(x, nknots = round(length(x)/winlen))$y
    },
      # If this fails use rolling average padded with NAs
    error = function(e){
      print(paste("Spline replaced by rollmean for:  ", id))
      return(zoo::rollmean(x, winlen, fill = NA))
    },
    warning = function(w){}
  )
  return(out)
}
```

Where x is the series, id is an identifier string and winlen both the factor to determine the number of knots for the spline and the length of the rolling average window.

And here is a reproducible toy example:

```
x_long  <- seq(1,100)
x_short <- seq(1,50)

# Returns the spline smoothed without error as expected
Mysmooth.spline(x_long, 25, "id_long")

# Returns the rolling average as expected but also prints many times an error
Mysmooth.spline(x_short, 25, "id_short")
# Returns many "spar-finding: non-finite value -nan; using BIG value" error
#[1] "Spline replaced by rollmean for:   id_short"
```

Though the result is correct, I'd really like to get rid of these annoying errors, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting some inspiration from a now-deleted answer I came up with a working solution:

```
Mysmooth.spline <- function(x, winlen, id){
  require(zoo)
  out <- tryCatch(
    {
      # Try to fit a cubic spline
      logger <- file("log.txt", open = "wt")
      sink(logger, type="message")
      smooth.spline(x, nknots = round(length(x)/winlen))$y
    },
    # If this fails use rolling average padded with NAs
    error = function(e){
      message(paste("Spline replaced by rollmean for:  ", id))
      return(zoo::rollmean(x, winlen, fill = NA))
    },
    warning = function(w){},
    finally = {
      sink(type = "message")
      close(logger)
    }
  )
  return(out)
}
```

This function returns all error messages to a log file instead of printing them in the console. When calling this function thousands of times, this results in a great boost of speed and doesn't pollute the console with red messages. Note that I also used `message()` to report the id of the problematic series, such that it will also be returned to the log file. A simple pattern extraction can then be performed on this file to extract the id.